# dynamic highlight region should move along with data points when changes occur in dygraph

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Is it possible to dynamic highlight points, for example data is 
`2015/08/09 10:55:46,-54.`, in `-54` a point is plotted, I need a dynamic highlight on top and bottom say `-54+10 = -44, -54-10 = -64.,`.

So whenever new data is updated say `2015/08/10 10:55:46,-14.`, `top +10` and `bottom -10` i.e data point will be in center and its highlighted around it with +-10., so -14 will be center and highlight top will be `-14 + 10 = -4` and for highlight bottom `-14 - 10 = -24`., gradually value will be updated and dynamic highlight also should move along with point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dygraphs` has already a function for this.
Your data must e.g. look like this:

```
Date, Value1, Value2, Value3
2015-9-16 14::,39;42;45,-3;0;3,16;19;22
```

where for `Value1` the real value = 42, bottom = 39 and top = 45 (can you change as needed, e.g. -10 or +10)

[image]